# How to change the divider color for the whole app in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose, can anyone tell me how can I change the divider color for the whole application? I can't assign a value to each place because doing so is time-consuming and easy to forget in a large application.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your custom `Divider`, and then use it in the application instead of the standard `Divider`.

Something like:

```
@Composable
fun CustomDivider(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Blue)
{
    Divider(modifier,color)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For [Material3](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3), you can do this by changing the `outlineVariant` color in your `Theme.kt` file:

```kotlin
private val WhiteColors = lightColorScheme(
    primary = white_primary,
    onPrimary = white_onPrimary,
    secondary = white_secondary,
    surface = white_primary,
    outlineVariant = <ADD_YOUR_COLOR_HERE>,
)
```